# get arb key from child widget

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, internationalization

I am facing problems that is I cannot get arb key from child widget when using translation in flutter.

All I can get is text contains itself.

I want to get arb key string.

Is there any solution??

Answer (score 0):

Key are so you can get access to the value, if you need to get access to the key make it a value.

Comment: i can't do that arb key is fixed by the others